# Permutation for either three consecutive number among the first four or last three among the first four

Tags: combinatorics

Let $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$, be a 4-element permutation with $b_i ∈{1, 2, 3,.......,100}$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ 4$ and $b_i ≠ b_j$ for $i ≠ j$, such that either $b_1, b_2, b_3$, are consecutive integers or $b_2, b_3, b_4$, are consecutive integers. Then the number of such permutations $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$, is equal to _____.

The official answer is 18915.
My approach is as follow

[image]

The first figure the number of ways is

$\frac{{96 \times 97}}{2}$

The second figure the number of ways is

$\frac{{96 \times 97}}{2}$

For third figure the number of ways is

$97$

Therefore my answer is $96 \times 97+97=9409$

Hence where I am making mistake

Comment: Can you reproduce the **exact** wording of the question ?

Comment: “$b-1$”…what is $b$? You haven’t defined it.

Comment: This question come in jee main exam I copied the question as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse engineering, $(18915)$ is the result of

$$[2 \times 98 \times 97] - \color{red}{97}. \tag1 $$

First, I will explain the above computation, then I will examine your posting.

First of all, I am interpreting the phrase $4$ *number permutation* 
to represent that you take any $4$ distinct elements from $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ and then order them in any of $(4!)$ ways.

So, $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,2,4,3)$ are considered distinct permutations.

For a $4$ number permutation, where the first three elements are in consecutive order, there are $(98)$ distinct numbers which may be used as the first number in the permutation.  Once this number is selected, the next three numbers in the permutation are fixed. Then, there are $97$ remaining numbers that may represent the last number in the permutation.

To clarify, one example of the type of permutation referred to above is $(98,99,100,50)$.

The factor of $(2)$ applied in (1) above reflects that you can also have permutations of form $(50,98,99,100)$, where the last $3$ elements of the permutation are in consecutive order.

In (1) above, the $\color{red}{\text{second term}}~$ represents that when constructing a $4$ number permutation where all four numbers are in consecutive order, there are $(97)$ possible numbers that may occupy the first position in the permutation.  Once this number is chosen, the remaining $3$ positions in the permutation are fixed.

In (1) above, the reason that the second term is deducted from the first term is explained by examining the computation of $(2 \times 98 \times 97)$ more closely.  In each computation $98 \times 97$, any $4$ number permutation where all $4$ numbers are in consecutive order is counted.

This implies that in the computation of $(2 \times 98 \times 97)$, any $4$ number permutation where all $4$ numbers are in consecutive order $\color{red}{\text{is counted twice}}$.

This explains the deduction.

---

Your posting represents an alternative approach to the computation.  This alternative approach is also viable.

Your idea is to create two sets:

- One in which the first three elements are in consecutive order.
- One in which the next three elements are in consecutive order.

Consider the permutation where the first three elements are 
$(3,4,5).$  That is, a permutation that looks like $(3,4,5,x).$

You assumed that there were only $94$ choices for the $4$th element in the permutation, namely the elements in $\{7,8,9,\cdots,100\}.$

This is wrong for two reasons:

- Each of the following permutations must also be included: 
  $(3,4,5,1), (3,4,5,2)$.
- The following permutation must also be included.
  $\color{red}{(3,4,5,6)}$.

So, you always have $97$ possible numbers that can be chosen for the $4$th position in the permutation.  Further, when constructing the permutations in this way, where there are $98$ choices for the first number, you inevitably create $97$ permutations where $\color{red}{\text{all 4 numbers are in consecutive order}}.$

That is, for the $98$ permutations that resemble 
$\{(1,2,3,x), (2,3,4,x), \cdots, (97,98,99,x), (98,99,100,x)\}$, 
in all but the very last one, you will end up creating a specific permutation that consists of $4$ consecutive numbers.

This analysis forces you to revert to the approach taken at the start of my answer.

**Edit**
I took a closer look at your approach, to see how it could be refined, with as little change as possible.

Consider the permutations where the first $3$ elements are in consecutive order.  Suppose that you want to exclude those permutations where there are $4$ consecutive numbers.

There are $98$ choices for the first number in the permutation, so you have $98$ subsets.

In $97$ of these subsets, you have only $96$ choices for the last element.  In the $98$th subset, namely $(98,99,100)$, you have (instead), $97$ choices for the last element in the permutation.

So, the Math here would be

$$\left\{~2 \times \left[ ~(97 \times 96) + 97 ~\right] ~\right\} + 97 = 18915.$$

Comment: Excellent explanation anybody can understand the question with the detailed explanation